# Why does COUNT match two JOIN values with only a specific one is specified

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

When I JOIN two tables, why does the COUNT() match values for both joins for *only* p.id = 9 (where -1st asterix- is JOIN #1-Start and -2nd asterix- is JOIN #2-Start), when it's only specified to match it for JOIN #2?

In other words 'id 9' should bring back 1 count since it only has 1 comment, but it's matching the result from the first join too for some reason.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(c.post_id) 
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN votes v ON p.id = v.post_id
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY  `c`.`comment` DESC 

+-----+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+
| id  | post  | (*) id | post_id | rating | (*) id  | comment | post_id | COUNT(c.post_id) |
+-----+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+
| 9   | test8 | 50     | 9       | 1      | 35      | testtt  | 9       | 2                |
| 5   | test4 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL   | 27      | tester  | 5       | 4                |
| 8   | test7 | NULL   | NULL    | NULL   | 26      | test    | 8       | 5                |
| 6   | test5 | 5      | 6       | 1      | 37      | hello   | 6       | 1                |
| 2   | test1 | 2      | 2       | 0      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | 0                |
| 4   | test3 | 3      | 4       | 1      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | 0                |
| ... | ...   | ...    | ...     | ...    | ...     | ...     | ...     | ...              |
| ... | ...   | ...    | ...     | ...    | ...     | ...     | ...     | ...              |
+-----+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're joining 3 tables. That creates a cross-product, with a row for each vote. If you want to count each comment only once, use `COUNT(DISTINCT c.comment_id)`.

Comment: This makes all the matched COUNTs equal to 1, which isn't what I'm after -- all the other current COUNT values are correct - it shows how many comments the posts have

Comment: Ah, I think it should be `COUNT(DISTINCT c.comment_id)`. You want to count the number of comments per post, not the number of posts per comment.